# Analytics Studio App - Showing only 1 record Sample data

Tags: salesforce1-app, einstein-analytics, einstein

I am trying to create my first Analytics App. After selecting the data for app creation, I am also getting an email for successful App creation. However, I see that it's not doing analytics on the Org Data but just 1 sample record is coming.

Also, I have waited for a day but no difference. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Really appreciate assistance over this...

Thanks & Regards,
Varun Gulati

Comment: Hi Varun, can you please add details like how did you create data set and dataflow for this dashbaord. Also please check on how many records it is showing in the DataFlow.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for the response. But I did not create the dataset separately... Here's what I did. Create - app - choose template - select all the dataset like logins, Apex errors, etc for which you want to create app - confirm... That's it

Comment: Please check how many records are there in the dataflow used in the dataset you are using. Run the dataflow once and check if it shows more records.

Comment: Hello Rohit, how can I check that... I know to reach the dataflow, but what to check further

Comment: Hi Rohit, just checked... So there are multiple rows in and rows out and no failures for various nodes in the entire data flow. Any idea what may be the issue as these aren't reflecting in the app

Comment: which template did you select while creating app? Also, did you create datasets like logins, Apex errors or they were already there?

Comment: Hi Rahul, so far I reached to  a point where the dataset behind has just one record and I am trying to figure out why... Any ideas